# Android Service don't restart onStartCommand

Tags: android, service, restart

I have a service class that verify position between a marker and a circle.

```
public class VerifyPositionService extends Service{

public static boolean isRunning;
private float[] distance = new float[2];
int i;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    i = 0;
    if (MainActivity.circles.size() > 0){
        for(Circle c : MainActivity.circles){
            Location.distanceBetween( MainActivity.marker.getPosition().latitude, MainActivity.marker.getPosition().longitude,c.getCenter().latitude, c.getCenter().longitude, distance);
            if( distance[0] < c.getRadius()  ){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "out" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "none" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
```

}

So, in my main activity, in method onCreate, I instantiate the service one time:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, VerifyPositionService.class);
startService(intent);
```

The service run only one time, giving me the toast: none.

When I add circles, the service don't return messages.. It would give me the toast: in, or out.
Can anyone helpme?

Answer (score 0):

The service only runs the start method once, when it starts. Your service will continue to run, but in the example you are not doing anything.

Since you receive "none" in your toast, you do not have any circles in your MainActivity at the time when your service starts.

You need to put your position verification code into some other method, and ask your service execute whenever you want it to.
Or, if you want to perform the calculation periodically, put the code inside a thread and start the thread in the onStartCommand method. Also, put a sleep inside the thread to specify how often you would want the method to be executed.

Comment: How I ask my service to execute? Thanks. The sleep of thread sleep's all aplication.

Comment: use startService(); What did you use before? No, sleep inside a thread only sleeps that thread. EDIT: I see you already use startService(). What are you asking?